# О разновидностях бэкапов

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Есть метки:

- [резервное-копирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)
- [backup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backup)
- [бэкап](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bf)

На мой взгляд это абсолютно одно и то же и подлежит синонимизации. Вы знаете какой-нибудь случай, когда это не так?

---

UPD: объединил.

- Созданы синонимы,
- Метки заменены на [резервное-копирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Comment: Если за сутки не появится возражений, проведу объединение всех меток в [tag:резервное-копирование].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Резервное копирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - аналог английского [backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup). Так что, это абсолютно одно и тоже.  [бэкап](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bf) просто американизм. Я бы всё это дело синонимизировал.